# Wiring plug for gas range w/electronic control panels

Tags: electrical, wiring, splicing

I am working with an existing wire from the panel. That wire is 'from' a 15amp breaker but is 4ga. Under the range I need a 15amp plug for the range. What is the best/safest way to splice from a 4ga to a 12ga wire so that I can install a plug? Should the splice be done in its own junction box and then out of that to the box for the plug? Can wire nuts of the appropriate size be used? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably in this situation because originally there was an electric cooktop and/or oven in that location, though 4 AWG seems larger than usual. Depending on wire and cable type, 4 AWG can handle at least 65A and often more. That's more "subpanel size" than "oven size", so you may want to verify that it is truly 4 AWG. There are wire nuts that work with 6 AWG.

I don't think you'll find wire nuts rated for 4 AWG. If you can find one that is rated for 1 x 4 AWG + 1 x 12 AWG, then you can use that.

If not, [Polaris connectors](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Polaris-4-14-AWG-Bagged-Insulated-Tap-Connector-Black-IT-4B/303577920):

[image: Polaris connector]

are the way to go. As far as box size, you will likely need more than the standard size single gang box. You can either use one junction box for the splice and another for the receptacle or use a larger box for everything.

**Double-check your breaker.** It may not be rated for 4 AWG wire, and shoving 4 AWG wire into a connection not rated for it is not to code and not a good idea.

Comment: So the OP would need to pigtail the end of the hot conductor in the box with a smaller wire, e.g., a #12 or whatever  the breaker would accept?

Comment: @JimStewart Correct. But the catch is that 4 AWG (if it truly is 4 AWG) won't work with standard wire nuts, which would mean Polaris.